# The function to_excel of pandas generate an unexpected TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I created a dictionary of pandas dataframe:

`d[k] = pd.DataFrame(data=data[i])`

So I assume that `d[k]` is a correct pandas dataframe.

Then

```
for k in d.keys():
  d[k].to_excel (file_name)
```

Then I have the error:

`TypeError: got invalid input value of type <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>, expected string or Element`

I am using Python 3.7, pandas 0.25.3.

**Update**: if I replace `to_excel` by `to_csv`, the code runs perfectly.

Comment: what is `file_name`? is it a string?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just something like ``'/data/myfile.xlsx'``

Comment: what happens if you try `d[k].to_excel(str(filename))`?

Comment: Same issue. I don't think the problem lies on the ``file_name``. I checked and am quite sure that it is a valid file name.

Comment: I got the same error using
Openpyxl: 3.0.2
pandas 0.25.3
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] Removing openpyxl 3.0.2 and upgrading openpyxl to 3.0.3 fixed the issue, as others report. Thank you.
One thing I'll add: the openpyxl 3.0.2 bug corrupted the *.xlsx file it was appending to, making it unreadable and unrecoverable by Excel.

Comment: I've encountered the exact same problem and the provided answer seems to work perfectly; please mark that as the correct answer if it helped for you :)

Answer (score 46):

I have same problem with `openpyxl=3.0.2`,

Refer to this [answer](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Need-help-in-understanding-this-particular-Traceback-TypeError), I roll openpyxl back to 3.0.1(conda or pip) and it works.

```
>>> conda remove openpyxl
>>> conda install openpyxl==3.0.1
```

or

```
>>> pip uninstall openpyxl
>>> pip install openpyxl==3.0.1
```

Comment: Tracked here: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1396/301-vs-302-saving-xlsx-file-bug

Comment: This issue has been fixed in openpyxl 3.0.3.

Comment: To fix the same issue as the OP had, I just ran "conda update openpyxl" from within Spyder, which seemed to upgrade it successfully to v3.0.3. Now I can't start Spyder or Jupyter Lab or anything :( . 

ImportError: image not found (for Spyder)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server' (for Jupyter Lab)

Comment: @Animeta thanks for the answer. It worked. Facing the same issue.