# Openpyxl yields TypeError on saving file, why?

Tags: anaconda, openpyxl, python-3.7

since the last package update the following code does not run any more. (This is an example, i have a couple of scripts that unfortunately require this functionality) The following code snippet is the simplest example i can imagine which worked before.

Current specs:
Win10 64bit,
Python 3.7.5 64bit,
IPython 7.10.2,
conda 4.8.0,
openpyxl 3.0.2

```
def write_to_default_excel():
    wb = Workbook()    
    wb.save('sample.xlsx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_to_default_excel()
```

yields:

```
TypeError: got invalid input value of type <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>, expected string or Element
```

I tried downgrading the openpyxl to 3.0.0 or 2.6.4., however conda cannot resolve the resulting dependency conflicts.

Any ideas why this happens out of the sudden? What am i missing/overlooking?
Can you recommend any alternative packages?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. It seems to be a bug of new version openpyxl package. You need to roll back to older version to get it work or you can switch to xlsxwriter & xlrd packages.

Check these posts for more information:
[The function to_excel of pandas generate an unexpected TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168758/the-function-to-excel-of-pandas-generate-an-unexpected-typeerror)

[openpyxl can't save to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375704/openpyxl-cant-save-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

The previous articles talk about reverting to OLDER versions of `openpyxl`. I have confirmed that using `pip` instead of `conda` to install the LATEST version (3.0.3 as of this writing) resolves this issue.